# Solving a simple matrix multiplication/evaluation problem in a shorter/simpler way

Tags: matrices

I've solved the following problem by calculating matrix A's entries as variables and then evaluating them using the system of linear equations. As I'm a bit new to matrices, I wanted to know whether there are shorter ways to solving this problem cause solving it from the way I did seems so long...

If $$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 2 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix} . A =\begin{bmatrix} 
 3 & 5 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 3 & 4 \\
 \end{bmatrix} . A =\begin{bmatrix} 
 -1 & 2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

what's the value of
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 8 & 9 \\
 \end{bmatrix} . A
$$

$A$ is a matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use that matrix multiplication is linear: $(av+bw)A=a(vA)+b(wA)$, where $v,w$ are vectors and $a,b$ are numbers. With $[8~9]=[2~1]+2\cdot[3~4]$, you can find $[8~9]A$ quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can notice that

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 8 & 9 \\
 \end{bmatrix} = 2\begin{bmatrix} 
 3 & 4 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 
 2 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 8 & 9 \\
 \end{bmatrix} A= 2\begin{bmatrix} 
 3 & 4 \\
 \end{bmatrix} A+\begin{bmatrix} 
 2 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix} A = 2\begin{bmatrix} 
 -1 & 2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 
 3 & 5 \\
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 9 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$ by linearity.